# Uploading files onto Windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ftp, ftps

I have VPS on Windows web server 2008 which I am using for hosting my own sites and project. Only mine. And I am currently solving an issue of how to upload files onto server. Sure, I am using FTP over SSL integrated server in IIS but I think it is little overkill and is actually possible security hole. I do not neet to let many users upload onto server (or delete files) - what I need is that only I can admin files on server.

So would you please refer me some other technology or is the FTP over SSL the best solution (even if it looks to me as overkill)?

Answer (score 3):

FTP over SSL isn't overkill. It protects your session from eavesdropping etc. As you have it set up you may as well keep using it.

Answer (score 0):

WebDAV or VPN+CIFS both seem like easy-to-implement solutions, and both are possible with software that ships with Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I am not completely sure if VPN is supported in Web Server edition of Windows server 2008. I will have to look into it.

Comment: WebDAV over SSL would be a perfectly good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in file transfer ability via Remote Desktop, which presumeably you already use to manage the server.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html).

It will provide a secure SSL connection to the server. Then you can use FTP, CIFS, RDP, etc over this VPN tunnel.